# Editing Drupal Search SQL

Tags: search

I'm using the basic Drupal Search module (search.module) and I want to customize the SQL of the search. I don't know how to go about doing this.

There are two things I want to edit in the SQL:

1) Have the search return ONLY nodes with start dates (event_start_date) AFTER now.

And

2) Return results in ascending order.

Pretty basic stuff.

Perhaps I need to use another search module entirely. I don't know.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do an alteration to a specific search query before, here's my general code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {

  if (get_class($query) == 'PagerDefault') {
    foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
      if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
        $query->join('field_data_field_event_start_date', 'sd', 'n.nid = sd.entity_id');
        $query->where('sd.field_event_start_date_value >= CURRENT_DATE')
          ->orderBy('sd.field_event_start_date_value');

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't want to alter other queries so I used a couple of checks to narrow down that I was altering a search query.

You may need to adjust your table/field names as appropriate, and if you wanted to order by title ASC rather than date just change the orderBy to 'n.title'

Comment: Thanks @thumbson. Where do you place the alter query, in template.php?

Comment: @Sage yes you could put it in template.php as MYTHEME_query_alter() or in a custom module.

Comment: Very good; thank you very much! I wish I could give both of you the correct answer but since this was what I was primarily looking for I'll give it to you. Thanks again.

Comment: one final question: I'm playing around with your code; it works! However I'd like to add a condition such that the search also returns fields that don't have a date set at all (so it should return both items greater than the current date OR with no date set). Here's what I've tried (and it doesn't return items with no date set): $query->where('fdfed.field_event_dates_value >= CURRENT_DATE' OR 'fdfed.field_event_dates_value IS NULL')
I just edited your SQL with that...that sql works in another application I've created but not for this. Thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: To get nodes not in the event date table you'll need to change $query->join to $query->leftJoin. Your 'where' clause looks good but from your comment does have some extra quotes, try `$query->where('fdfed.field_event_dates_value >= CURRENT_DATE OR fdfed.field_event_dates_value IS NULL')`

Answer (score 2):

The [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module provides a `Search` view out-of-the-box (it's disabled). I would:

1. Turn off the default `Search` module.
2. Install Views.
3. Clone the default `Search` view in the Views administration page and call it `My SITENAME Custom Search`.
4. Add whatever filters you want to this View like the date criteria you list and adjust the deafult sorting if needed.

**tip:** you can easily search all the text in say the `title` **and** `body` field(s) of your Nodes with 1 text search box by adding a `Filter` of type `Global: Combine Filter` which uses the `title` and `body` fields in your `Views: Fields` section.

note for really really really massive sites you'll want to actually use a robust search engine. But as a proof of concept or small site (less than says tens of thousands of nodes) this should work Ok.

**EDIT**

To use the existing site search mechanism you would use `hook_query_alter` to change the query array to add `SQL` conditions to the `Where` clause of the query statement with whatever conditions you want. Note, that *perhaps* you may not have the sql fields needed for the query logic (you might thought). And if thats the case you would then need to use sql `Joins` to be able to reference the fields in SQL you want to do business logic on. Then add/modify a `sort by` sql clause, the same caveats about fields applies here again.

My Views solution above is 5 minutes worth of simple configuration and then adjusting some CSS. This solution could be 5 minutes if all the fields are in the SQL query already -- or much longer to figure out the necessary joins and syntax. The [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module can help you inspect the raw search query. Good luck.

Comment: and if I want to stay with the default search (due to other customizations already haven taken place in the tpl and template files among other things)...is there a way to edit just the SQL?

Thanks for your tips. This is important possibility to consider.

Comment: Hi, please see my edit @Sage For maintainability, I'd recommend my approach as it doesnt muck with core *behavior*. I've done things like what you've asked (excluded nodes from the default search) ... it's tedious and when you upgrade drupal, or hire a new developer they may wonder why the default search is *odd* on *this* site.